# in factory - zero article?

Tags: articles, zero-article

In an English grammar book I found this sentence:

> Sarah got a job **in factory**.

Is the absence of an article legitimate here?

I would say the correct usage would be: **... in a factory**.

Am I correct?

Comment: It sounds strange to me without the article. Is there some context, which might explain it, or is it just the sentence by itself?

Comment: It sounds strange to me too, that's why I asked. No, no more meaningful context: Sarah got a job in factory. Five years later...

Comment: Then I would assume, that it is a typo. I mean, it is not unheard of, that there are typos in publications of any kind.

Comment: Can't "factory" be used as a synonym for "factoring" ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - Using *factory* as a synonym for *factoring* would be confusing at the very least, since by far the most common meaning of *factory* is "a big building where something is made".  And I'm not sure it would make much sense to say she got a job "in factoring", either.

Comment: @stangdon I wonder if the people working in factoring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoring_(finance)) would agree with you.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - Fair enough!  In my defense, that's kind of a specialized technical term; I'd never heard of it before you linked to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct (If using American english). "in a factory" should be the correct term.

Typically, you would use "in x" to denote an occupation. For example "Sarah got a job in landscaping" or "Sarah got a job in marketing".

Since you are indicating a generic location like a "factory", you need the "a". If factory was an occupation however, the statement in the book would be right.

Answer (score 1):

You will hear the noun without article in certain contexts:

> Our customers can shop online on in store.

and **in store** there would usually be spoken much as **online** is spoken, without the typical pause that occurs between words. **in** and **store** would be treated rather like syllables of the same word, and you might fight them hyphenated: **in-store**.

There the meaning is generic.  The reference is not to a particular store, but to the **mode** of shopping.

Thus, under appropriate circumstances you could say **in factory**

> Are these features added to the car by the dealership or in factory?

although **at the factory** would be more common. The reference there in either case (zero article or **the**) is not to a particular factory but to a generic factory, to *how in the context of vehicle assembly and preparation*  the features get added.

As always, the choice of article reveals the speaker's thought.  You would be far more likely to hear **in factory** from someone whose daily work involves manufacturing and distribution logistics than from someone whose only knowledge of factories is that they are large buildings often with smoke-stacks, where stuff gets made.